# Two EFI partitions in dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, disk

Sorry if this has been asked before but there are many things I don't understand right now and I'm scared of messing up :(

This is what my disks look like right now:

[image: disk mgmt screencap]

Is it safe/okay to have two EFI partitions like that? Is there a way to know which one is being used when I boot my PC? Would it be safe to delete one of them somehow?

And my main problem right now: if i shrink the "data" partition will I be able to grow the Ubuntu partition (72 GB) even if the space is not adjacent? if so what are the steps I need to follow to archive that?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of questions, here’s some quick answers.

1. Your computer will boot the drive you tell it to. You set that in the BIOS/UEFI. In Ubuntu if you use the lsblk command in a terminal it will show you which EFI is mounted. That’s the one being used.
2. It’s perfectly ok to have two EFI partitions but only one on each disk.
3. If you check your BIOS/UEFI and determine which EFI partition is being used it might be possible to delete the other one but I wouldn’t recommend it. With a EFI partition on both drives you have a chance of booting the other disk if one fails.

To make more space for your Ubuntu partition do the following:

1. Backup any data you cannot afford to lose
2. Using Windows disk manager shrink your data partition
3. Boot into a live environment, your Ubuntu install media is fine for this
4. Using GParted move the small EFI partition all the way to the left. Apply the change
5. Using GParted expand your Ubuntu partition into the space created. Apply the change and reboot.

Good luck